# ReactJs .NET Core App 1.1 on OS X doesn't render or gives engine's error

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, macos, reactjs

Trying to build a ASP .Net Core App on OS X Sierra and everything looks fine until I try to add ReactJS components. 
The solution provides what I thought should have been enough/necessary, but in Safari nothing is rendered. I have to scenarios:

1. React Code embedded in HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remarkable/1.7.1/remarkable.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/jsx">

var HeaderBox = React.createClass({
render: function(){
    return(
    <p>Test Header</p>
    );
}

});

ReactDOM.render(<HeaderBox />, document.getElementById('content'));

</script>
```

2. React in JSX file (Exception)

> Error initialising React.VroomJsEngine+Factory:
>   JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core.JsEngineLoadException: During loading of
>   VroomJs JavaScript engine error has occurred.  See more details:
>
> The type initializer for 'VroomJs.JsEngine' threw an exception. --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'VroomJs.JsEngine' threw an exception. --->
>   System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'VroomJsNative': The
>   specified module could not be found.  (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E)    at
>   VroomJs.JsEngine.js_set_object_marshal_type(JsObjectMarshalType
>   objectMarshalType)    at VroomJs.JsEngine..cctor()

I followed all the React guidelines (I already used it with node and it worked always) and the ASP.NET solution without React works perfectly. I'm starting to doubt that maybe React is not well supported on OS X yet.